# What is $.Deferred() and .resolve in jquery

Tags: jquery

What does `.deferred()` do? What is its work, and when and where should we use it with `resolve`?
In the below function, I have two `.done()` callbacks. I want to set two different callback messages.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLpBB/)

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
deferred.done(function(value) {
    alert(value);
}).done(function(id){
alert(id)
});

console.log(deferred)

deferred.resolve("hello world");
```

Comment: Just to clarify your question, do you want the two alert's to show a different message?

Comment: yes I want to show different message and also want to understand .deferred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jQuery.Deferred` is the main tool of jQuery's implementation of the promise pattern.

Here are a few links, worth reading :

- [[SO] Implement promises pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245867/implement-promises-pattern)
- [[jQuery doc] Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)
- [[wikipedia] Futures and Promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)

As for your specific need : you should use `.then()` (read the docs for [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) and [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)).

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

deferred.then(function(value) {
    alert(value);
    return 42;
}).then(function(id){
    alert('The answer : ' + id);
});

console.log(deferred)

deferred.resolve("hello world");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLpBB/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Would this do what you want?

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
deferred.done(function(value) {
    alert(value[0]);
}).done(function(value){
    alert(value[1]);
});


deferred.resolve(["hello world", "goodbye, cruel world"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I want to know the same result we can get without using .deferred so why .deferred is useful see http://jsfiddle.net/WLpBB/1/

Comment: This answer is missing is educational explanation.